# UITableViewCell becomes unresponsive

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover screen, with inside it :

- a label, that may or may not appear (title)
- a search bar, that may or may not appear
- a label, that may or may not appear, and has a variable height (help label)
- a scrollview, that may or may not appear, and has a variable height (some infos about the following table)
- a table view

In order to present something nice, in `viewDidLoad`, I move the various frames to place the objects correctly and not have unused spaces cluttering my popover. Besides, I then resize the table (to take the most place needed), and the popover via `contentSizeInPopover` (to avoid having a near-empty huge popover). All that resizing seems to work nicely, but I have one big problem : with all that resizing done, some cells of my UITableView become unresponsive. One or two cells, usually the second one, only respond if i tap in their outer corners, but the rest of the cell completely ignore any touches.

I've tried everything : moving all to `viewWillAppear`, letting the autoresize do its job (doesn't seem to work either), but I still have this problem every time. I've found that if I comment the lines involved with changing the `frame` of the table, or the ones in `contentSizeInPopover`, the problem stops, but then my view is messed up, so this ins't a fix.

If anyone could give me something to get out of this mess, that would be awesome.

```
- (CGFloat)getHeightWithoutTable {
    return LIST_TITLE_HEIGHT + (self.searchBar.hidden ? 0 : LIST_SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT) + (self.helpLabel.hidden ? 0 : self.helpLabel.frame.size.height + LIST_STD_SPACE) + (self.errorScrollView.hidden ? 0 : self.errorScrollView.frame.size.height + LIST_STD_SPACE);
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableViewOutlet.backgroundView = nil;
    self.originData = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.searchedData = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (self.helper != nil) {
        CGFloat heightOffset = 0;
        // Content
        self.originData = [self.helper getData];
        self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.originData];
        // Title
        NSString *title = [self.helper getPopoverTitle];
        if (title == nil) {
            self.popoverTitle.hidden = YES;
            heightOffset -= LIST_TITLE_HEIGHT;
        } else {
            self.popoverTitle.text = [self.helper getPopoverTitle];
        }
        // Search
        if ([self.originData count]  [self getStdHeight] / 3){
                self.helpLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
                [self.helpLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.helpLabel.frame.size.width, [self getStdHeight] / 3)];
            }

            heightOffset += (self.helpLabel.frame.size.height - LIST_HELP_STD_HEIGHT);
        }
        // Errors
        if ([self.helper respondsToSelector:@selector(getErrors)]) {
            self.errors = [self.helper getErrors];
        }
        if (self.errors == nil || [self.errors count] == 0) {
            self.errorScrollView.hidden = YES;
            self.errorBg.hidden = YES;
            heightOffset -= LIST_ERROR_STD_HEIGHT + LIST_STD_SPACE;
        } else {
            [self createErrorView];
            heightOffset += (self.errorScrollView.frame.size.height - LIST_ERROR_STD_HEIGHT);
        }
        // Table
        CGFloat previewHeight = LIST_CELL_HEIGHT * [self.tableData count] + LIST_STD_SPACE;
        CGFloat remainingHeight = LIST_MAX_HEIGHT - [self getHeightWithoutTable] - LIST_STD_SPACE;
        CGFloat tableHeight = MIN(previewHeight, remainingHeight);
        CGRect tableFrame = self.tableViewOutlet.frame;
        self.tableViewOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(tableFrame.origin.x, tableFrame.origin.y + heightOffset, LIST_WIDTH, tableHeight);
        // Selected items
        if ([helper getSelectedObject] != nil){
            int index = [self.tableData indexOfObject:[helper getSelectedObject]];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
            [self.tableViewOutlet scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover {
    if (self.navigationController) {
        return CGSizeMake(LIST_WIDTH, LIST_MAX_HEIGHT);
    } else {
        CGFloat totalHeight = [self getHeightWithoutTable] + self.tableViewOutlet.frame.size.height + LIST_STD_SPACE;
        return CGSizeMake(LIST_WIDTH, totalHeight);
    }
}
```

([gist](https://gist.github.com/2037694) if you need some coloring to help you)

An image of the nib :

[image: nib]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself : the fact I was using a self-filled UIScrollView next to my UITableView seemed to be the problem. As soon as I replaced the UIScrollView by a proper UITableView, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, since you have not provided any code. If you are adding things to the UITableCellView, just remember that a lot of components have their `UserInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`, which will disable the ability to interact with it. Make sure that any items you add to the cell that potentially take up the space where you are tapping (presumably the center of the cell?) have their `UserInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`.

The reason why the edges might still work is that the UITableCellView consists of 3 main parts, so you are probably only changing the center part.

Post some code then we can have a better look.